# How to convert a dictionary that is in string form into dictionary form in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, data-structures

I have a string as this, and I want to convert it into dictionary.

```
test=
'{"age":59.0,"bp":70.0,"sg":1.01,"al":3.0,"su":0.0,"rbc":1.0,"ba":0.0,"bgr":76.0,"bu":186.0,"sc":15.0,"sod":135.0,"pot":7.6,"hemo":7.1,"pcv":22.0,"wbcc":3800.0,"rbcc":2.1,"htn":1.0,"dm":0.0,"cad":0.0,"appet":0.0,"pe":1.0,"ane":1.0}'
```

I tried `dict(test)` but it retuned an error as:

```
ValueError: dictionary update sequence element #0 has length 1; 2 is required
```

How can I convert this string to a dict?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using [ast.literal_eval](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval)

```
import ast

new_dict = ast.literal_eval(test)
```

Comment: This solution may be the best one, you don't have to worry about whether the string is inside single quotes or double quotes, and it also will not cause security issues.

Answer (score 2):

Your string is in JSON format, so you can use the `json` module to turn it into a dict:

```
>>> test = '{"age":59.0,"bp":70.0,"sg":1.01,"al":3.0,"su":0.0,"rbc":1.0,"ba":0.0,"bgr":76.0,"bu":186.0,"sc":15.0,"sod":135.0,"pot":7.6,"hemo":7.1,"pcv":22.0,"wbcc":3800.0,"rbcc":2.1,"htn":1.0,"dm":0.0,"cad":0.0,"appet":0.0,"pe":1.0,"ane":1.0}'
>>> import json
>>> json.loads(test)
{'age': 59.0, 'bp': 70.0, 'sg': 1.01, 'al': 3.0, 'su': 0.0, 'rbc': 1.0, 'ba': 0.0, 'bgr': 76.0, 'bu': 186.0, 'sc': 15.0, 'sod': 135.0, 'pot': 7.6, 'hemo': 7.1, 'pcv': 22.0, 'wbcc': 3800.0, 'rbcc': 2.1, 'htn': 1.0, 'dm': 0.0, 'cad': 0.0, 'appet': 0.0, 'pe': 1.0, 'ane': 1.0}
>>>
```

Note that if you're writing a Python dictionary out as a string, you should always prefer `json.dumps(data)` to `str(data)` -- JSON format is portable across languages, and if you get in the habit of encoding and decoding data using common formats you're less likely to accidentally do something really bad like using `eval()` for decoding.  You may also sometimes find when converting data using `str()` that it gets truncated for display purposes, since `str()` is generally meant for printing, not for data serialization.